# Помогите написать цикл для программы в Python

Tags: python, циклы

Задание звучит так: Известны результаты каждой из 4х четвертей баскетбольной встречи. Нужно определить победителя матча. Побеждает команда, набравшая больше очков в течение всего матча.

Входные данные
Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит 4 строки, в каждой строке находится два целых числа a и b – итоговый счет в соответствующей четверти. а – количество набранных очков за четверть первой командой, b – количество очков, набранных за четверть второй командой. (0 ≤ a,b ≤ 100).

Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите номер выигравшей команды, в случае ничьей следует вывести «DRAW».

Я написала такую программу:

```
a1,b1=map(int,input().split())
a2,b2=map(int,input().split())
a3,b3=map(int,input().split())
a4,b4=map(int,input().split())
a=a1+a2+a3+a4
b=b1+b2+b3+b4
if a==b:
    print('DRAW')
if a>b:
    print('1')
if a<b:
    print('2')
```

Понимаю, что как-то можно написать циклом. Например, если строчек будет 40. Я же не буду вот так вручную писать. Но даже идеи нет, с чего подступиться. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать цикл просто по всем строчкам в файле. Для этого рекомендуется открывать файл при помощи "менеджера контекста" with ... as. Он сам закроет файл даже в случае ошибок. Для записи в файл OUTPUT открываем его в режиме записи 'w'. В таком режиме содержимое файла будет перезаписано, если файла нет - он будет создан.

```
a_sum = 0
b_sum = 0
message = 'DRAW'
with open('INPUT.TXT') as file:
    for line in file:
        a_score, b_score = map(int, line.split())
        a_sum += a_score
        b_sum += b_score

if a_sum > b_sum:
    message = '1'
elif a_sum < b_sum:
    message = '2'

with open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w') as file:
    file.write(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Врятли цикл понадобится при использовании `input()` но, как говорится, спрашивали - отвечаем:

```py
def result(score: str):
    team_1, team_2 = map(int, score.split())
    print((team_2 > team_1) + 1 if team_1 != team_2 else 'DRAW')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        try: # в данном случае это обход ошибки эмулятора ввода.
             # возникающей в тот момент когда файл из которого берутся данные заканчивается
             # на самом деле данные читаются из файла
             # собственно как и там где Вы взяли эту задачку
            result(input())
        except EOFError:
            break
```

А вот при чтении данных из файла вполне себе может пригодиться:

```py
def result(score: str):
    team_1, team_2 = map(int, score.split())
    print((team_2 > team_1) + 1 if team_1 != team_2 else 'DRAW')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open('score.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as score_file:
        for line in score_file.readlines():
            result(line)
```

Comment: Минус. Вопрос в том, чтобы определить победителя игры, а не победителя каждой четверти.

Comment: А как бы вы написали эту программу без цикла, но максимально коротко?

Comment: @Irina. Вот отсюда `for line in score_file.readlines():` цикл начинается

Comment: @Эникейщик вопрос был про реализацию цикла а не про решение задачи

Comment: @OleLukøje про реализацию цикла для решения задачи. Этот цикл задачу не решает.